# Get vehicle registration details from apisetu.gov.in API

Tags: api, rest, postman, token

I am trying to implement a feature in my website where user can input the Vehicle's Registration Number and pull out the details of the vehicle and owner. Similar to https://jankari.loconav.com/rc
There is an API provided by the government of India to achieve this -  https://ndh.digitallocker.gov.in/public/api/transport#/APIs/drvlc but there is no documentations involved. I am not even sure how to use it in postman. There are no options to generate an API key etc. When you click the "try" button it just shows you a pre-written json which gives error after you execute it. Can some help me find a way to build something similar to https://jankari.loconav.com/rc using the http://apisetu.gov.in

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the shortest way would be to send an email to the government? Their address is on this page: https://apisetu.gov.in/contactus.php

Comment: Hey, did you finally get an answer to this problem? Facing the same issue. How do I get generate the clienId and apiKey ?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to the problem?

Comment: Hello, any update?

Comment: any soln...it says sign in with digilocker account i did than it is asking company details...not available for individual use? than whats the use